# get the caller script of an exported function

Tags: bash, function, export, parent, pid

I have a script /usr/bin/test.sh which looks like that:

```
test_func()
{
    echo "callertest 1:"
    cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline | tr '\0' ' '
    echo "callertest 2:"
    ps aux | grep $PPID
}

export -f test_func
bash -c test_func
```

Because "/usr/bin" is in $PATH, i call the script with "test.sh". The function should echo the script's name or better full path, but i havent got any further than getting "bash". Seems to be an issue with scripts which are placed in $PATH.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `bash -c test_func` instead of simply `test_func` (in which case the `export` is not necessary)? Your problem is that `test_func` isn't being run directly by `test.sh`, but by another shell started by `test.sh`.

Comment: What output are you getting from running that? I see the scriptname in the output when I run it here.

Comment: @chepner: It was just an example. I want to execute the function parallelized, each with several different parameters. Let's say i want to call the function 10 times with one of the parameters 1, ..., 10, so i call something like `seq 10 | xargs -n 1 -P $(nproc) -I {} bash -c "test_func {}"`

Comment: @EtanReisner: did you set the executable bit for the script and called it with its full path? When i call it with `/usr/bin/test.sh`, both tests just show `-bash` as result.

Comment: Yes. Add a shebang line to your script and you should see it to. As written your current shell is running the script (as a fallback) because your system doesn't know what else to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cover all cases:

```
get_scriptname()
{
    SCRIPTFILE=$(readlink -e -- "${0}" 2>/dev/null)
    until [ -e "${SCRIPTFILE}" ] || [ "$_PPID" = "0" ] ; do
        _PPID=$(awk '{print $4}' /proc/${_PPID:-$$}/stat 2>/dev/null)
        CMDLINE=$(awk -F '\0' '{print $2}' /proc/${_PPID}/cmdline 2>/dev/null)
        READLINK=$(readlink -e -- "${CMDLINE}" 2>/dev/null)
        WHICH=$(which -- "${CMDLINE}" 2>/dev/null)
        SCRIPTFILE=${READLINK:-${WHICH}}
    done
}

test_func()
{
    get_scriptname
    echo "${SCRIPTFILE}: $1"
}

export -f test_func get_scriptname
bash -c "test_func param0"
echo -e "param1\nparam2\nparam3" | xargs -n 1 -i bash -c "test_func {}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function, put your code in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "callertest 1:"
cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline | tr '\0' ' '
echo "callertest 2:"
ps aux | grep $PPID
```

make sure it is executable:

```
chmod +x test_script.bash
```

then execute it with `xargs`:

```
seq 10 | xargs -n 1 -P $(nproc) ./test_script.bash
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution with a function as before, as it's faster for a lot of iterations

Comment: Then you can't use `xargs`, since it needs to run a new `bash` shell for each call to the function.

Comment: More generally, a single `bash` process cannot run multiple functions in parallel, since it isn't threaded.

Comment: So then i have to `export PARENT=$0` in the parental shell and use this Variable, if there is no other way to not change the complete structure. I thought it can't be to hard to get the script's name that a bash instance is executing.